# Relative importance/Variation partitioning in a GLM containing an interaction

Tags: r, glm, interaction, variance

I have a question regarding the **relative importance of variables, in a GLM that contains an interaction (continuous * factor).**

I am experimenting with an approach based on **partitioning the explained variation, approximated through (pseudo)-R-squared**. But I am unsure of how to that (1) in a GLM, and (2) with a model that contains an interaction.

For simplicity, I have prepared an example model with a Guassian GLM with a single interaction (using mtcars dataset, see code at the end of the post). But I am actually interested in applying the method to a Generalized Poisson GLM, which might contain multiple interactions.
A few questions arise from the test model:

1. **How to partition the R-squared correctly?** I have attempted a partition, but I’m unsure if that’s the right way.
2. **The r-squared of each term do not add up to the r-squared of the full model (not even close).** This also happens with a model that contains no interaction. Aside from mistakes in partitioning the r-squared (I still consider myself a newbie to stats :P); could this also be influenced by collinearity? The variance inflation factors are below 3 after scaling the continuous predictors (a model with no scaling has the highest VIF = 5.7).

Any help much appreaciated!

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rsq)
library(car)

data <- mtcars %>%
  # scale reduces collinearity: without standardizing, the variance inflation factor for the factor is 5.7
  mutate(disp = scale(disp))
data$am <- factor(data$am)

summary(data)

# test model, continuous response (miles per gallon), type of transmission (automatic/manual) as factor, displacement as continuous
model <-
  glm(mpg ~ am + disp + am:disp,
      data = data,
      family = gaussian(link = "identity"))
drop1(model, test = "F")

# graph the data
ggplot(data = data, aes(x = disp, y = mpg, col = am)) + geom_jitter() + geom_smooth(method = "glm")

# Attempted partitioning
(rsq_full <- rsq::rsq(model, adj = TRUE, type = "v"))

(rsq_int <- rsq_full - rsq::rsq(update(model, . ~ . - am:disp), adj = TRUE, type = "v"))

(rsq_factor <- rsq_full - rsq::rsq(update(model, . ~ . - am - am:disp), adj = TRUE, type = "v"))

(rsq_cont <- rsq_full - rsq::rsq(update(model, . ~ . - disp - am:disp), adj = TRUE, type = "v"))

c(rsq_full, rsq_int + rsq_factor + rsq_cont)

car::vif(model)


# A simpler model with no interaction
model2 <- glm(mpg ~ am + disp, data = data, family = gaussian(link = "identity"))
drop1(model2, test = "F")

(rsq_full2 <- rsq::rsq(model2, adj = TRUE, type = "v"))
(rsq_factor2 <- rsq_full2 - rsq::rsq(update(model2, . ~ . - am), adj = TRUE, type = "v"))
(rsq_cont2 <- rsq_full2 - rsq::rsq(update(model2, . ~ . - disp), adj = TRUE,type = "v"))

c(rsq_full2, rsq_factor2 + rsq_cont2)

car::vif(model2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Joseph Luchman for sharing this methodology over at GitHub!

A few strategies to deal with the relative importance of interactions are presented in: LeBreton, J. M., Tonidandel, S., & Krasikova, D. V. (2013). Residualized relative importance analysis: A technique for the comprehensive decomposition of variance in higher order regression models. Organizational Research Methods, 16(3), 449-473.

They discuss the strategy of calculating the increase in R2 when the interaction is added. Moreover, the contribution of the interaction to the R2 "alone" could be done with residualization: taking the residuals of a regression that models the product between variables as a function of the additive effects of the variables: https://github.com/jluchman/domir/discussions/5

The resulting residualized interaction could be used in dominance analysis, which takes a model, and splits R-squared (or other metric of model quality like AUC), into independent contributions by each of the independent variables. It can be implemented in R with the domir package (https://github.com/jluchman/domir).

Answer (score 1):

Given:

1. `y = A + B + A * B`

I would compare its R-squared value to that of its simpler versions:

2. `y = A + B`
3. `y = A`
4. `y = B`

If there is no interaction, I expect

```
r-squared(model1) = r-squared(model2)
```

This should apply to any linear model. It should also be useful for comparing the main effect of the predictors even if there is an interaction. I know this is contentious, but if you look at the scenario represented in the figure below, predictor A is only informative if predictor B is taken into account; conversely, predictor B holds some predictive power even by itself (y for B1 is higher than y for B2, regardless of the level of A which they belong to).

[image]

Here is an example with simulated data (to avoid issues of collinearity and non-normality):

```
# simulate data:
df <- data.frame(Species = as.factor(c(rep("Species A", 200),
                            rep("Species B", 200)
                            )),
                Treatment = as.factor(rep(c("diet 1", "diet 2","diet 1", "diet 2"), each=100)),
                body.weight = c(rnorm(n=100, 30, 5),
                                rnorm(n=100, 29.9, 5),
                                rnorm(n=100, 55, 5),
                                rnorm(n=100, 90, 5)
                                )
                )
```

[image]

```
# Let's fit and compare the alternative models:
lm.interactive <- lm(body.weight ~ Species * Treatment, data=df)
lm.additive <- lm(body.weight ~ Species + Treatment, data=df)
lm.only.species <- lm(body.weight ~ Species, data=df)
lm.only.Treatment <- lm(body.weight ~ Treatment, data=df)
lm.null <- lm(body.weight ~ 1, data=df)

# obtain R^2:


summary(lm.only.Treatment)$adj.r.squared # main effect of Treatment
summary(lm.only.species)$adj.r.squared # main effect of species ID. 
# As the figure suggests, it's larger than the main effect of Treatment 
# (species identity affects body weight regardless of treatment)
summary(lm.additive)$adj.r.squared # sum of the main effects
summary(lm.interactive)$adj.r.squared # main effects + interaction

# fraction of variance explained by the interaction alone:
summary(lm.interactive)$adj.r.squared - summary(lm.additive)$adj.r.squared
```

I'm not sure if we can really talk of "fraction of variance explained by the interaction *alone*" though. Talking of increase in explained variance thanks to the inclusion on an interaction term may be more appropriate.

I'm not sure of how statistically sound the approach I'm suggesting is, of its limitations, or whether it works reliably for unbalanced datasets. One issue with this approach is that the differences in R-squared cannot be tested statistically, given that we only have one R-squared value for each model. One way around it would be to obtain a distribution of R-squared values for each model using bootstrapping.

Comment: Thank you, this looks like a sensible approach. I wonder whether in a multivariate approach (suppose over 3 explanatory variables), maybe it would make more sense to calculate the drop in R^2 when a term is dropped from the model (rather than univariate models). By the way, in your example the R^2 add up quite nicely, but in my example the R^2 do not add up... I am thinking it is related to the GLM approach (not OLS), and the presence of collinearity (?). Also, apologies for the late reply! Cheers

Comment: If two or more of your predictors are continuous, collinearity is definitely a possibility. I wouldn't know how to address it though.

Comment: ...I wouldn't know how to address collinearity, short of sequentially dropping predictors involved in collinearity. See "Step 5: Is there collinearity among the covariates?" in doi: 10.1111/j.2041-210X.2009.00001.x and references within for further details. If two predictors are collinear, estimates of their main effects are bound to be biased by it. I suspect that the same applies to any interaction between collinear predictors.